# Two requests in one time immediatly. ASP MVC + JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

MVC application (ASP.NET MVC, client: jquery).

Problem: The second ajax-request wait, when the first ajax request will done.

I need, when the first and the second ajax-requests executes immediatly in one time.

The page sends to server to determine the count of records (the first ajax-request), very long (~5-7 seconds).
The operator click the buttom to open the card to edit it (the second ajax-request, fast, get the Dto-model).
The user doesn't need to wait the first request, he wants to work immediatly.

As a result, in Chrome in network page, two requests in status 'pending'. The second waits the first.

Question, how can I send requests, to execute asynchronously ?

The first ajax-request:

```
`window.jQuery`.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: Url.Action("GetCountBooks", "Book");
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",          
dataType: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify({ typeBook: "...", filter: "..." };),
success: function (data) {
    // show in UI page the count of books by filter and params
},
error: function (data) {
    //show error
}});

public class BookController : Controller
{   
    [HttpPost]
    public NJsonResult GetCountBooks(string typeBook, Filter filter)
    {
        var data = DbProvider.GetCountBooks(typeBook, filter)
        if (data.Result == ResultType.Success)
        {
            var count = data.Data;

            return new NJsonResult
            {
                Data = new { Data = count }
            };          
        }

        return new NJsonResult
        {
            Data = new { Error = "Error while counting the books." }
        };
    }
}
```

The second ajax-request:

```
`window.jQuery`.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json",
url: Url.Action("GetBookById", "Book"),
data: JSON.stringify({ id: bookId }),
success: function (data) {
   // show jquery dialog form to edit dto-model.
},
error: function (data) {
   //show error
}});

public class BookController : Controller
{   
    [HttpPost]
    public NJsonResult GetBookById(int id)
    {
        var data = DbProvider.GetBookById(id)
        if (data.Result == ResultType.Success)
        {
            var book = data.Data;               
            return new NJsonResult
            {
                Data = new { Data = book }
            };
            return new NJsonResult
            {
                Data = new { Error = "The book is not found." }
            };
        }    
        return new NJsonResult
        {
            Data = new { Error = "Error while getting the book." }
        };
    }
}
```

I Cannot union ajax requests into one! The user can send various second request.

Comment: Can you supply the HTML and javascript code that performs the calls, so we can see what is blocking?

Comment: You already have two asynchronous calls. If you are calling one and waiting for a result to allow the user to click a button then that could be an issue. Can you put up your code that demonstrates how the calls are made please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add attribute to Asp Controller: [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]

http://johnculviner.com/asp-net-concurrent-ajax-requests-and-session-state-blocking/

Answer (score 2):

You need a fork-join splitter to fork 2 tasks and join based on some condition.

For example here is my implementation:

```
function fork(promises) {
  return {
    join: (callback) => {
        let numOfTasks = promises.length;
        let forkId = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000);
        fork_join_map[forkId] = {
            expected: numOfTasks,
            current: 0
        };
        promises.forEach((p) => {
            p.then((data) => {
                fork_join_map[forkId].current++;
                if (fork_join_map[forkId].expected === fork_join_map[forkId].current) {
                    if (callback) callback(data)
                }
            })
        });
    }
}}
```

Pass any number of async tasks (promises) into `fork` method and `join` when all are done. The **done** criteria here is managed by simple global object `fork_join_map` which tracks the results of your fork-join process (global is not good but its just an example). The particular fork-join is identified by `forkId` which is 0..1000 in this example which is not quite good again, but I hope you got the idea.

With jQuery you can create promise with `$.when( $.ajax(..your ajax call) )`

In the end you can join your promises like this

```
fork([
  $.when( $.ajax(..your ajax call 1) ),
  $.when( $.ajax(..your ajax call 2) )
]).join(() => {
  // do your logic here when both calls are done
});
```

It's my own implementation, there may be already-written library functions for this in jQuery - I dont know. Hope this will give you a right direction at least.

Comment: please note that this example has a lot of problems, for example it doesnt handle faulty ajax responses and you will never go to join method, but again - it's just an example for understanding

Comment: I Cannot union ajax requests into one! 
The user can send various second request.

Comment: You said that the problem is that ajax calls are sequential and you need to execute them simultaneously in parallel - why you cannot call them? I mean, ok, the user may send many requests - then just put them all in fork(ajax1, ajax2, ajax3, ...)

Comment: Can you give me some easy examples how to use ajax and promises? And good documentation. Thank You!

Comment: I gave you example how to use promises in jQuery with when, here you can read about it more https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: The solution is to add attribute to Asp Controller:
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]

Link: http://johnculviner.com/asp-net-concurrent-ajax-requests-and-session-state-blocking/